# Elasticsearch Receiving Parse Error on production

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch to index my jobvacancy collection. I run it on my production server (V4.10.4) and on my homestead vagrant box (V4.10.4).

Both of these servers use to same code to build their index.

However, when running a query it returns a valid empty response on my development box, and an invalid query response on my production environment.

**CURL request**

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" 'http://localhost:9200/jobs/job/_search' -d '{
  "sort": {
    "networks.start": {
      "order": "desc",
      "mode": "max",
      "nested_filter": {
        "term": {
          "networks.id": 10
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "*Manager*",
                "fields": [
                  "name^2",
                  "text",
                  "description",
                  "company_name^2"
                ],
                "default_operator": "AND"
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "*Manager*",
                "fields": [
                  "name^2",
                  "text",
                  "description",
                  "company_name^2"
                ],
                "default_operator": "AND"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "segments": "BXnGVL2o"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "segments": "dpjdEZ3R"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "segments": "vrLORZ0E"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "segments": "GkLe1Lp5"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "segments": "0zjrvjYW"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "segments": "vRnpPny1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "networks",
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "networks.id": 10
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "networks.status.raw": "PRODUCTION"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "networks.start": {
                          "lte": "now"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "networks.end": {
                          "gte": "now"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "networks.start": {
                          "gte": "2015-10-04"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "category_main": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_id"
      }
    },
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "categories"
      }
    },
    "segments": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "segments"
      }
    },
    "max_salary": {
      "max": {
        "field": "salary"
      }
    },
    "min_salary": {
      "min": {
        "field": "salary"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0
}'
```

**Response on development**

```
{
    "took": 12,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "min_salary": {
            "value": null
        },
        "segments": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
        },
        "max_salary": {
            "value": null
        },
        "category_main": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
        },
        "categories": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
        }
    }
}
```

**Response on Production**

```
{
    "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[MaoAOhMzQnCtHsNCUW3PIQ][jobs][0]: SearchParseException[[jobs][0]: from[-1],size[-1],sort[<custom:\"networks.start\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@5c9703f2>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"sort\":{\"networks.start\":{\"order\":\"desc\",\"mode\":\"max\",\"nested_filter\":{\"term\":{\"networks.id\":10}}}},\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*Manager*\",\"fields\":[\"name^2\",\"text\",\"description\",\"company_name^2\"],\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*Manager*\",\"fields\":[\"name^2\",\"text\",\"description\",\"company_name^2\"],\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"BXnGVL2o\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"dpjdEZ3R\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"vrLORZ0E\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"GkLe1Lp5\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"0zjrvjYW\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"vRnpPny1\"}}]}},\"filter\":{\"and\":[{\"nested\":{\"path\":\"networks\",\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"term\":{\"networks.id\":10}},{\"term\":{\"networks.status.raw\":\"PRODUCTION\"}},{\"range\":{\"networks.start\":{\"lte\":\"now\"}}},{\"range\":{\"networks.end\":{\"gte\":\"now\"}}},{\"range\":{\"networks.start\":{\"gte\":\"2015-10-04\"}}}]}}}}]}}},\"aggs\":{\"category_main\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"category_id\"}},\"categories\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"categories\"}},\"segments\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"segments\"}},\"max_salary\":{\"max\":{\"field\":\"salary\"}},\"min_salary\":{\"min\":{\"field\":\"salary\"}}},\"size\":10,\"from\":0}]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"BXnGVL2o\"]; }{[MaoAOhMzQnCtHsNCUW3PIQ][jobs][1]: SearchParseException[[jobs][1]: from[-1],size[-1],sort[<custom:\"networks.start\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@3e84345b>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"sort\":{\"networks.start\":{\"order\":\"desc\",\"mode\":\"max\",\"nested_filter\":{\"term\":{\"networks.id\":10}}}},\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*Manager*\",\"fields\":[\"name^2\",\"text\",\"description\",\"company_name^2\"],\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*Manager*\",\"fields\":[\"name^2\",\"text\",\"description\",\"company_name^2\"],\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"BXnGVL2o\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"dpjdEZ3R\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"vrLORZ0E\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"GkLe1Lp5\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"0zjrvjYW\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"vRnpPny1\"}}]}},\"filter\":{\"and\":[{\"nested\":{\"path\":\"networks\",\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"term\":{\"networks.id\":10}},{\"term\":{\"networks.status.raw\":\"PRODUCTION\"}},{\"range\":{\"networks.start\":{\"lte\":\"now\"}}},{\"range\":{\"networks.end\":{\"gte\":\"now\"}}},{\"range\":{\"networks.start\":{\"gte\":\"2015-10-04\"}}}]}}}}]}}},\"aggs\":{\"category_main\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"category_id\"}},\"categories\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"categories\"}},\"segments\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"segments\"}},\"max_salary\":{\"max\":{\"field\":\"salary\"}},\"min_salary\":{\"min\":{\"field\":\"salary\"}}},\"size\":10,\"from\":0}]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"BXnGVL2o\"]; }{[MaoAOhMzQnCtHsNCUW3PIQ][jobs][2]: SearchParseException[[jobs][2]: from[-1],size[-1],sort[<custom:\"networks.start\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@522f0274>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"sort\":{\"networks.start\":{\"order\":\"desc\",\"mode\":\"max\",\"nested_filter\":{\"term\":{\"networks.id\":10}}}},\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*Manager*\",\"fields\":[\"name^2\",\"text\",\"description\",\"company_name^2\"],\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*Manager*\",\"fields\":[\"name^2\",\"text\",\"description\",\"company_name^2\"],\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"BXnGVL2o\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"dpjdEZ3R\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"vrLORZ0E\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"GkLe1Lp5\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"0zjrvjYW\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"vRnpPny1\"}}]}},\"filter\":{\"and\":[{\"nested\":{\"path\":\"networks\",\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"term\":{\"networks.id\":10}},{\"term\":{\"networks.status.raw\":\"PRODUCTION\"}},{\"range\":{\"networks.start\":{\"lte\":\"now\"}}},{\"range\":{\"networks.end\":{\"gte\":\"now\"}}},{\"range\":{\"networks.start\":{\"gte\":\"2015-10-04\"}}}]}}}}]}}},\"aggs\":{\"category_main\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"category_id\"}},\"categories\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"categories\"}},\"segments\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"segments\"}},\"max_salary\":{\"max\":{\"field\":\"salary\"}},\"min_salary\":{\"min\":{\"field\":\"salary\"}}},\"size\":10,\"from\":0}]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"BXnGVL2o\"]; }{[MaoAOhMzQnCtHsNCUW3PIQ][jobs][3]: SearchParseException[[jobs][3]: from[-1],size[-1],sort[<custom:\"networks.start\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@c4a37d3>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"sort\":{\"networks.start\":{\"order\":\"desc\",\"mode\":\"max\",\"nested_filter\":{\"term\":{\"networks.id\":10}}}},\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*Manager*\",\"fields\":[\"name^2\",\"text\",\"description\",\"company_name^2\"],\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*Manager*\",\"fields\":[\"name^2\",\"text\",\"description\",\"company_name^2\"],\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"BXnGVL2o\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"dpjdEZ3R\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"vrLORZ0E\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"GkLe1Lp5\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"0zjrvjYW\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"vRnpPny1\"}}]}},\"filter\":{\"and\":[{\"nested\":{\"path\":\"networks\",\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"term\":{\"networks.id\":10}},{\"term\":{\"networks.status.raw\":\"PRODUCTION\"}},{\"range\":{\"networks.start\":{\"lte\":\"now\"}}},{\"range\":{\"networks.end\":{\"gte\":\"now\"}}},{\"range\":{\"networks.start\":{\"gte\":\"2015-10-04\"}}}]}}}}]}}},\"aggs\":{\"category_main\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"category_id\"}},\"categories\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"categories\"}},\"segments\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"segments\"}},\"max_salary\":{\"max\":{\"field\":\"salary\"}},\"min_salary\":{\"min\":{\"field\":\"salary\"}}},\"size\":10,\"from\":0}]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"BXnGVL2o\"]; }{[MaoAOhMzQnCtHsNCUW3PIQ][jobs][4]: SearchParseException[[jobs][4]: from[-1],size[-1],sort[<custom:\"networks.start\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@c4a37d3>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"sort\":{\"networks.start\":{\"order\":\"desc\",\"mode\":\"max\",\"nested_filter\":{\"term\":{\"networks.id\":10}}}},\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*Manager*\",\"fields\":[\"name^2\",\"text\",\"description\",\"company_name^2\"],\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*Manager*\",\"fields\":[\"name^2\",\"text\",\"description\",\"company_name^2\"],\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"BXnGVL2o\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"dpjdEZ3R\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"vrLORZ0E\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"GkLe1Lp5\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"0zjrvjYW\"}},{\"match\":{\"segments\":\"vRnpPny1\"}}]}},\"filter\":{\"and\":[{\"nested\":{\"path\":\"networks\",\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"term\":{\"networks.id\":10}},{\"term\":{\"networks.status.raw\":\"PRODUCTION\"}},{\"range\":{\"networks.start\":{\"lte\":\"now\"}}},{\"range\":{\"networks.end\":{\"gte\":\"now\"}}},{\"range\":{\"networks.start\":{\"gte\":\"2015-10-04\"}}}]}}}}]}}},\"aggs\":{\"category_main\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"category_id\"}},\"categories\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"categories\"}},\"segments\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"segments\"}},\"max_salary\":{\"max\":{\"field\":\"salary\"}},\"min_salary\":{\"min\":{\"field\":\"salary\"}}},\"size\":10,\"from\":0}]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"BXnGVL2o\"]; }]",
    "status": 400
}
```

Is there anyone that knows how this problem could occur? Thank you,

Comment: `NumberFormatException[For input string: \"BXnGVL2o\"];` your `segments` field is not what you are expecting it to be. Can you provide the mapping for this field?

Comment: You are entirely correct, I'm rather new with Elasticsearch, and not yet proficient in reading the errors. The mapping is indeed mapped to a long, and not a string. Somehow I'm entering encoded ids into the query, which should have been decoded before.